# Spring AMQP multi-threaded producer

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a multi-threaded application that uses a RabbitTemplate (with CachingConnectionFactory) to send messages to the broker. I need to ensure that the messages are delivered in order. 
I have seen this answer about this myself in: [Spring AMQP ensuring message order in multi-threaded environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242254/spring-amqp-ensuring-message-order-in-multi-threaded-environment)

Are these the only two options with Spring AMQP? What does a dedicated connection mean? I need to define a new RabbitTemplate with its ConnectionFactory in each java class that serves as the producer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versions 2.0 and later now support [scoped operations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#scoped-operations) where all operations within the scope of the `invoke` occur on the same channel.

Of course "in order" can only mean in order within each thread.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using version 1.7 and it's not easy to change in the short term. What would be the most effective way to use a dedicated connection and guarantee the order of the messages?

Comment: Please respect my time and don't ask the same question in multiple places; I already answered this question in reply to the same comment in my answer to the question you cited above. "With 1.7.x, perform the publishes within the scope of an `execute()` operation. Or you could create your own ConnectionFactory that stores a channel for each thread in a ThreadLocal".

Comment: Sorry, I wrote in the wrong place (I just wanted to write here) and seeing nothing in this I thought I had not sent it. I'm sorry again, and thanks.